# proof covariance from $\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l(x_j-\mu_X)(y_i-\mu_Y)P(X=x_j,Y=y_i)$

Tags: statistics, covariance

I know how to prove covariance by the linearity of expectation end up with $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$, but I want to separate the case to digest deeply, I am a bit stuck at a discrete case below. How should I play around with this joint pmf.

$cov(X,Y)=E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]=\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l(x_j-\mu_X)(y_i-\mu_Y)P(X=x_j,Y=y_i)$

Much appreciated for discrete and continuous case separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that I understand what your entire question, but I do understand that you want to know how to proceed from $\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l(x_j-\mu_X)(y_i-\mu_Y)P(X=x_j,Y=y_i)$ for a direct proof of the covariance formula $\mathrm{cov}(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$. To that end, note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l(x_j-\mu_X)&(y_i-\mu_Y)P(X=x_j,Y=y_i) 
\\&= 
\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l[x_j y_i - \mu_X y_i - \mu_Y x_j + \mu_X \mu_Y]P(X=x_j,Y=y_i)
\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^lx_j y_iP(X=x_j,Y=y_i) - 
\mu_X\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l y_iP(X=x_j,Y=y_i)
\\ & \quad - \mu_Y \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^lx_jP(X=x_j,Y=y_i)
\\ & \quad +\mu_X\mu_Y \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^l P(X=x_j,Y=y_i)
\\ & = 
\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^lx_j y_iP(X=x_j,Y=y_i) - 
\mu_X\sum_{i=1}^k y_iP(Y=y_i)
\\ & \quad - \mu_Y \sum_{j=1}^lx_jP(X=x_j)
+\mu_X\mu_Y
\\ & = E(XY) - \mu_X E(Y) - \mu_YE(X) + \mu_X\mu_Y
\\ & = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) - E(Y)E(X) + E(X)E(Y) 
\\ & = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y).
\end{align}
The proof for the continuous is essentially the same except that the probability mass function is replaced by a probability density function and the iterated sums are replaced with iterated integrals.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My first attempt was $\sum_{i=1}^k (y_i-\mu_Y) \sum_{j=1}^l(x_j-\mu_X)P(X=x_j,Y=y_i)$, and I stuck. Can the latter become expectation somehow? I wobble about this.

Comment: @LJNG I don't really see any way to proceed there. You could write the inner sum as a [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation), but I don't think that this is a helpful step.